# Missing an assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

In a solution I am working on, in a sub project I have added a reference to another project.  After adding the reference, I was able to successfully add the using statement and have the auto-complete pick up the right extension I was looking for.  The code wrote as usual, but when I compiled, I get the error

> The type of namespace name 'Name1' does not exist in the namespace 'Name2' (are  you missing an assembly reference?)

So I have searched the forums, I have added several other system references and I have gotten nothing.  I ran NuGet to update the solution packages, and that didn't make a difference either.  For some reason, when I add the reference (using the add reference pop-up GUI) the reference to Name1 doesn't have a dll file in it.  If I browse to the dll file directly, it still gives me the same issue when compiling.

Comment: What is the target framework of the 2 projects?

Comment: Don't add a reference to a DLL, add an existing project to your subproject solution and add a reference to that project.

Comment: Also, don't forget to Clean and Rebuild the solution.

Comment: Target framework is .Net Framework 4.  I tried adding the reference properly, but that resulted in the reference having no dll in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can copy the dll to `[projectname] / Debug /`
or  `[projectname] / Release /`